# How to use escapeHtml in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml

In Magento 1 I used the code below for value:

```
value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getDefaultValue()) ?>
```

How could I set this code in Magento 2?

Comment: Have you try with above syntax in magento 2?

Comment: For all available escape methods refer to https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156368/magento-2-template-security-which-method-to-use

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
/**
 * Escaper
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
 */
protected $_escaper;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Escaper $_escaper
) {
    $this->_escaper=$_escaper
}
```

Now you can easily use `escapeHtml` by

```
$this->_escaper->escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags);
```

Or If you are using any block or `.phtml` file then you can use this by

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getDefaultValue()); ?>
```

**EDIT[As per requested]**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$escaper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($data);
```

Comment: thanks for reply how i use with object method in my template file

Comment: I have updated my answer  @Rahulocodewire

Comment: thank you its work can you tell me please one thing how i load this in magento 2 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);   its not work how i get the product id

Comment: You should try with the $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($‌​productId);  @Rahulocodewire

Comment: hi Keyur shah can you tell me please one thing how i get the custom option in the magento 2 this is my code   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);



 echo count($product->getOptions()); die;


 foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $options) {
 $optionType = $options->getType();
 $optionTitle = implode('_', explode(" ", $options->getTitle()));
 $options->getId();

Comment: I think for this you have to ask a new question so all the people in community can answer and for this question I already given answer to your question :) @Rahulocodewire

Comment: Your is not work also get error $data is   undefind variable

Comment: Please replace $data with $this->getDefaultValue(), In answer gave  to how to use this :) @Rahulocodewire

Comment: Glad  to hear that it is working @Rahulocodewire

Answer (score 9):

With the latest version of Magento 2.4 now you can directly use **$escaper** variable to use class `\Magento\Framework\Escaper`. The **$escaper** local variable is available inside the any `.phtml` templates.

```
<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($block->getDefaultValue()); ?>
```

Read More at: [XSS prevention strategies](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/xss-protection.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can use it in magento-2 like below

```
value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getDefaultValue()) ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the method "html_entity_decode"(http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)  like this

```
echo html_entity_decode ( $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') )
```

Comment: According to new Magento 2 Coding standard it is not safe to use PHP function html_entity_decode (https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard/blob/a916b11b4760093dfbd17a51752550ef30bf569a/Magento2/Sniffs/Functions/DiscouragedFunctionSniff.php#L164)

Answer (score 0):

Since `magento/framework` **100.2.0** you can call escape methods using `$block` variable in template files.

All available escape methods can be found in [\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php) class.