# Magento 2: template security: which method to use?

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, security, magento2.2.2

I'm aware Magento 2 has several methods available to secure the template:

- `$block->escapeHtml()`
- `$block->escapeQuote()`
- `$block->escapeUrl()`
- `$block->escapeXssInUrl()`

But I'm wondering when to use each of those methods ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is for Magento 2.0. For 2.1, refer to Fabian's answer

### `escapeHtml`

Use this function in the case of a string output that should not contain HTML.

Example:

```
<span class='label'><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel()); ?></span>
```

### `escapeQuote`

Use this function in the case of HTML attributes

Example:

```
<span class="<?php echo $block->escapeQuote($block->getSpanClass()); ?>">Description</span>
```

### `escapeUrl`

Use this function in case of an URL output (without XSS prevention - only character conversion)

Example:

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl()); ?>">Link</a>
```

### `escapeXssInUrl`

Use this function in case of an URL output (with XSS prevention - including character conversation)

Example:

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->escapeXssInUrl($block->getUrl()); ?>">Link</a>
```

### What does not need escaping ?

- Type casting and php function `count()` (example `echo (int)$var`)
- Output in single quotes (example `echo 'test'`)
- Output in double quotes without variables (example `echo "test"`)

### The `__` method

This one is used for translation purposes. Use it when you know a string can be translated.

For example:

```
<caption class="table-caption"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('More Information') ?></caption>
```

Comment: good job.. rapheal

Comment: Should we escape every translation `__()` too?
I'm a bit tired of pasting `/* @escapeNotVerified */` everywhere :/

Comment: @BartekIgielski see my updated answer. `__` is not for security purpose but for translation purpose

Comment: Thanks. So we have to add `/* @escapeNotVerified */` every time or wrap every translation in some escape function. Lame :<

Comment: `/* @escapeNotVerified */` should not be added. You should be add or `escepe*` or /* @escapeVerified */ for function is output html...

Comment: Also I recommend to escape translated strings, like `echo $this->escapeHtml(__('Text to translate'))`

Comment: @KAndy the example code I gave for `__` is from the core `product/view/attributes.phtml`

Comment: There is currently a note on the devdocs page that some methods will be deprecated with 2.2. Make sure to check back on the template security page. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-security.html

Comment: Also, there is a similar question here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143273/using-different-escaping-methods/143335#143335. `escapeXssInUrl` should not be used, better use `escapeUrl` instead.

Comment: Apparently escapeUrl should not be used for img href attribute: https://www.integer-net.com/why-you-should-not-use-escapenotverified-in-magento-templates/

Answer (score 57):

The escaping methods in `AbstractBlock` all delegate calls to `Magento\Framework\Escaper`, so you'll find an overview there.

Let's look at the public methods and their documentation:

#### escapeHtml()

```
/**
 * Escape string for HTML context. allowedTags will not be escaped, except the following: script, img, embed,
 * iframe, video, source, object, audio
 *
 * @param string|array $data
 * @param array|null $allowedTags
 * @return string|array
 */
public function escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags = null)
```

This should be your default escaping method for any output. **Convention is that the result of all methods that do not contain "Html" must be escaped.**

#### escapeHtmlAttr()

(*since Magento 2.2*)

```
/**
 * Escape a string for the HTML attribute context
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @param boolean $escapeSingleQuote
 * @return string
 */
public function escapeHtmlAttr($string, $escapeSingleQuote = true)
```

Use this to escape output within a HTML attribute, for example

```
title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr($title) ?>"
```

It will escape HTML, but also quotes (`"`)

By default, it will also escape single quotes, so this works too:

```
onclick="alert('<?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr($message) ?>')"
```

Set the second parameter to false if this is not desired.

#### escapeUrl()

```
/**
 * Escape URL
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @return string
 */
public function escapeUrl($string)
```

This can be used to output URLs. It will apply the default HTML escaping and additionally removes `javascript:`, `vbscript:` and `data:`. If you want to prevent URLs like this in user provided links, you can use the method.

*Until Magento 2.1 this feature was not included and you needed to use `escapeXssInUrl()` instead. There was no reason to use `escapeUrl()` at all.*

Otherwise, just use `$block->escapeHtmlAttr()` for URLs.

#### escapeJs()

(*since Magento 2.2*)

```
/**
 * Escape string for the JavaScript context
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @return string
 */
public function escapeJs($string)
```

Encodes unicode characters for JavaScript, for example `♥` becomes `\u2665`. Use it to escape output **within a JS string**. For inline Javascript (i.e. `onclick` attributes), you still need to call `escapeHtmlAttr()`.

Note that if you use `json_encode()`, it already does the same escaping, in this case, `escapeJs()` must not be used.

#### escapeCss()

(*since Magento 2.2*)

```
/**
 * Escape string for the CSS context
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @return string
 */
public function escapeCss($string)
```

Encodes unicode characters for CSS (see `escapeJs()`), for example to be used in the `content` CSS attribute.

### Deprecated methods (as of Magento 2.2):

- escapeJsQuote: Use `escapeHtmlAttr()` instead
- escapeXssInUrl: Use `escapeUrl()` instead
- escapeQuote: Use `escapeHtmlAttr()` instead

Comment: Good job I've added a little note to my answer to refer to yours when using 2.1. Interestingly, the Magento U couse only mentions the methods I've mentionned in my answer. I guess the course is 2.0 only

Comment: `escapeHtmlAttr` and `escapeHtmlAttr` doesn't exist in 2.1.2 ... at least not in `/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php` unless they've added it later and re-tagged magento ..

Comment: Good catch, my answer actually was based on the latest develop branch. According to the devdocs, the other methods will be deprecated from 2.2

Comment: Is there a method that can be used to clean an arbitrary chunk of html that might need to have an img tag in it?

Comment: Clean in which sense?

Comment: In Magento 2.3.2 AbstractBlock don't have **encodeUrlParam()**

Comment: So is it necessary to add escapeUrl to getViewFileUrl? Like this: "echo escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl("images/img.jpg"));"

Comment: echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl("images/img.jpg"))

Comment: As of Magento 2.4 all of these are deprecated :/

Comment: @bfontaine the same methods can be used, but with `$escaper` instead of `$block`  now

Answer (score 7):

For Magento 2.4 you shoud in phtml template use `$escaper->escapeHtml(...)` instead of `$block->escapeHtml(...)`. Full doc is available here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/xss-protection.html#output-processing